# why passing a string to a function is giving error

Tags: c++

I have seen like `char const* ca = str.c_str();` this is working fine in c++
 But like same if i am passing it as argument to a function its giving error

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
void send(char *p);
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string s="tuhin";
    send(s.c_str());

    return 0;
}
void send(char const* ca)
{
    cout<<*ca;
}
```

Please help

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: How is it you intend to use `std::string` without including `<string>`?

Comment: error is "error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'"

Comment: Thank you. Now it's *really* easy to answer!

Comment: `<string>` and `<string.h>` are very different headers, just so you know

Answer (score 1):

Your function prototype `void send(char *p);` does not match the function definition.

You need `char const* p` as the parameter in the prototype.

Also, replace the `cout` with `cout << ca;` to output the entire string, not just the first character.